# How to make Kusto make_list's maxSize parameter accept the value of a user function parameter?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

If I pass in a user function parameter to [`make_list()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/makelist-aggfunction)'s `maxSize`, I get the following error:

```
Relop semantic error: SEM0248: make_list() function expects an integer in range [1..1048576] for argument 2
```

Is there some way to tell Kusto that the parameter's value is valid?

Here's what my code approximately looks like:

```
let GetSaturatedVersions = (
        T:(time: datetime, version:string, server:string),
        ts:timespan = 10d,
        n:int = 10) {
    let saturated_versions = T
    | where time > ago(ts)
    | summarize by time = startofday(time), version, server
    | summarize count() by version, time
    | order by time asc, count_ desc
    | summarize
        Versions = make_list(version, n),
        Counts = make_list(count_, n)
        by time
    ;
    saturated_versions
};
GetSaturatedVersions(MyTable)
| take 100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and below are my expected results:

Firstly, received same error:

[image]

Then I have modified my KQL query like below:

```
let x= datatable(Col1: string)
[
    "A",
    "B",
    "C",
    "D",
    "E",
    "F"
];
let rithfun=(
T:(Col1:string),n:int=3)
{
T
| summarize MyList = make_list(Col1,case(n > 0 and n <= 1048576, n, 1048576))
};
rithfun(x)
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

[image]

[Fiddle.](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAAzXNPQvCMBCA4f1%20xdEpgQwtftIaQatOunUTkWijBtMITQr1678bbHO3PMu9p6XDlmMpnN%20TliR/6CRF62plrhT2gH6iRcQ6LAPygFXAOmATwSED7cO1crdLYziBIu3CfZeZVBnHBxTeUMAHbVNVolYvibvnVlmHHCtxl0ft/T9kZ2ElMTjHGIUp0eCMYxIPp6PJmKFhwZTCN4P%20L2npD5J/iGbfAAAA)

Here I have used **`case()`** operator for solving the error.

Alternatively, you can use like below too:

```
let x= datatable(Col1: string)
[
    "A",
    "B",
    "C",
    "D",
    "E",
    "F"
];
let n=3;
let rithfunx=(
T:(Col1:string))
{
T
| summarize MyList = make_list(Col1,n)
};
rithfunx(x)
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

[image]

[Fiddle.](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA8tJLVGosFVISSwBwqScVA3n/BxDK4XikqLMvHRNrmguBSBQclTSgTCcYAxnGMMFxnCFMdyUuGKtuXKABufZGkMYRZklGWmleRW2GlwhVhAroDZoclVzhXDVKBSX5uYmFmVWpSr4VvpkFpco2CrkJmanxucA2WANOnmaXLXWXDCTNCo0AXSi2pS7AAAA)

Comment: I think the first solution (not capturing N from the above context) is more reusable.
Basically, if you do a range check within the function using a `case` statement, it should work. Thanks!